# Why is this jQuery selector not selecting ALL the cells in the nth column?

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery selector:

```
$('#table td:nth-child(1)')
```

which returns:

```
<td>5</td>
```

why doesn't it return `<td>5</td>` AND `<td>3</td>`?  I want the whole `nth` (1st here) column.

Thanks.

Comment: works just fine -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FLJxg/), show us how you're using it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/8kcLZ/1/)

```
$('#table td:nth-child(1)').each(function(){
    // <td>5</td> AND <td>3</td>
});
```

This was just to display the element's returned by the selector

And what you did is absolutely correct `$('#table td:nth-child(1)')` [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/8kcLZ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

[It does.](http://jsfiddle.net/DprSg/)

```
alert($('#table td:nth-child(1)').size());
```

So... maybe test your code? :/

Answer (score 0):

This works. For first child i recommend `:first-child`

```
$('#table tr').each(function(){
    $('td:nth-child(1)', this).css( 'color', 'red' )
});
```